# A program that accepts a word and prints every letter on a new line (c)

Tags: c, arrays, newline, fgets

I have to make a program in c that accepts one word with no spaces and prints out each letter on a new line. However, I have to use fgets. I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LINE 4096

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char array[MAX_LINE];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(array,MAX_LINE,stdin);
        for(i=0; array[i]!='\0'; i++){  
            printf("%c\n",array[i]);

       }
       return 0;
}
```

But it keeps printing out an extra 2 lines at the end of the word. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

[`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) reads in the newline character into the buffer *if* there's enough space in the buffer. You can modify the condition to accommodate that:

```
for(i=0; array[i] != '\n' && array[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

man [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads the newline and store it in the buffer.

See also here:
[Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)